# auto complete textbox using oracle database (Improvement)

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle11g, textbox

> updated

```
   public class PopulateProduct
    {
        public string ProductDesc { get; set; }
        public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    }

    Dictionary<string, PopulateProduct> dict = new Dictionary<string, PopulateProduct>();

    public void load()
    {
        string connstr = "user id=rawpic;password=admin";
        string cmdtxt = @"select PRODUCT_ID,DESCRIPTION,UNIT_PRICE 
                              from products";

        AutoCompleteStringCollection autocom = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        TB_PRODUCT_ID.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
        TB_PRODUCT_ID.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        TB_PRODUCT_ID.AutoCompleteCustomSource = autocom;

        using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connstr))
        using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(cmdtxt, conn))
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    dict.Add((string)dr["PRODUCT_ID"],
                        new PopulateProduct()
                        {
                            ProductDesc = (string)dr["DESCRIPTION"],
                            UnitPrice = (decimal)dr["UNIT_PRICE"]
                        });
                    autocom.Add(dr["PRODUCT_ID"].ToString());
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,"",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }


    private void TB_PRODUCT_ID_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dict.ContainsKey(TB_PRODUCT_ID.Text)) 
        {
            TB_PRODUCTS_DESC.Text = dict[TB_PRODUCT_ID.Text].ProductDesc;
            TB_UNIT_PRICE.Text = dict[TB_PRODUCT_ID.Text].UnitPrice.ToString();
        }
    }
```

> ------ Old script below-------

I am using below code to auto complete `textbox`value data
then automatically change the value of another two `textboxs` 
product description and price the code below works fine but
the description `textbox` value not correct its get the last database record value so any suggestion about it ?

finally is there is faster way to do auto complete ??

note is not necessary to update description and price `textbox` synchronize right away with product id it may be happen after user select the product id 
like on select if that possible and faster please tell me how

```
    private void TB_PRODUCT_ID_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connstr = "user id=rawpic;password=admin";
        string cmdtxt = @"select PRODUCT_ID,DESCRIPTION,UNIT_PRICE 
                              from products";

        AutoCompleteStringCollection autocom = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        TB_PRODUCT_ID.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
        TB_PRODUCT_ID.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        TB_PRODUCT_ID.AutoCompleteCustomSource = autocom;

        using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connstr))
        using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(cmdtxt, conn))
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    autocom.Add(dr["PRODUCT_ID"].ToString());
                    TB_PRODUCTS_DESC.Text = dr["DESCRIPTION"].ToString();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tired to add parameter for the select statement at where part as below but that wont work out

```
        private void TB_PRODUCT_ID_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connstr = "user id=rawpic;password=admin";
        string cmdtxt = @"select PRODUCT_ID,DESCRIPTION,UNIT_PRICE 
                              from products
                           where PRODUCT_ID=:PRODUCTID";

        AutoCompleteStringCollection autocom = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        TB_PRODUCT_ID.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
        TB_PRODUCT_ID.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        TB_PRODUCT_ID.AutoCompleteCustomSource = autocom;

        using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connstr))
        using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(cmdtxt, conn))
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    autocom.Add(dr["PRODUCT_ID"].ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("PRODUCTID", TB_PRODUCT_ID.Text));
                    TB_PRODUCTS_DESC.Text = dr["DESCRIPTION"].ToString();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: With AutoCompleteStringCollection, you don't have to requery all the time!  Just initialize the collection with ALL words, and .Net handles the filtering of the suggestions as the user types. This should make your speed problem go away...

Answer (score 1):

You are only populating a list from the PRODUCT_ID result of your query.  The first example code block shows you are updating an `AutoCompleteStringCollection` but the description you are just overwriting the static text box with whatever the last item in the loop contains.

Also, you are executing this heavy code each time the text changes, that must be really sluggish.

Second example won't work as you are putting an item into the parameters collection but as you are in a using block that is disposed of when the loop completes (you wouldn't use parameters this way anyway).

One suggestion would be to create a dictionary of type  and fill that in your loop.  When your textbox changes you could use Dictionary[PRODUCT_ID].Description and .Price - this would increase application running speed as you wouldn't be going back to the database each time.

```
public class MyObject {
  string Description {get;set;}
  decimal UnitPrice {get;set;}
}

public Dictionary<string, MyObject> _dict = new Dictionary<string, MyObject>();

public void Load() 
{
    string connstr = "user id=rawpic;password=admin";
    string cmdtxt = @"select PRODUCT_ID,DESCRIPTION,UNIT_PRICE from products";

    AutoCompleteStringCollection autocom = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    TB_PRODUCT_ID.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
    TB_PRODUCT_ID.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
    TB_PRODUCT_ID.AutoCompleteCustomSource = autocom;       

    using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connstr))
    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(cmdtxt, conn))
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                _dict.Add(dr["PRODUCT_ID"], new MyObject() { Description = dr["DESCRIPTION"], UnitPrice = dr["UNIT_PRICE"] };
                autocom.Add(dr["PRODUCT_ID"].ToString());
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // handle exception
        }
    }
}

private void TB_PRODUCT_ID_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

if (_dict.ContainsKey(TB_PRODUCT_ID.Text))  
    {
        TB_PRODUCTS_KEY.Text = _dict[TB_PRODUCT_ID.Text].Description;
        TB_UNIT_PRICE.Text = _dict[TB_PRODUCT_ID.Text].UnitPrice.ToString();
    }
}
```

Like I say, one way to achieve this but without seeing your other code hard to tell if its the best way.

Comment: thanks for very useful replay and your explanations... I had read and tried your suggestion but i got error at that line  `_dict.Add(dr["PRODUCT_ID"]), new Object() { ProductDesc = dr["DESCRIPTION"], UnitPrice = dr["UNIT_PRICE"] };`

Comment: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,MyProject.Form1.Object>.Add(string, MyProject.Form.Object)' has some invalid arguments
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'
'MyProject.Form1.Object.ProductDesc' is inaccessible due to its protection level
'MyProject.Form1.Object.UnitPrice' is inaccessible due to its protection level .... I think these Error because I am defining the class at wrong section I have reviewed on the internet about c# define new class ? and defined after the namespace but I was not able to use the Dictionary keyword

Comment: I put the class within the form class and all the code works fine except the error I have told you about.... I also think there is something wrong with closing the brackets or something that caused that errors I tried to solve them but i fill.. please your help

Comment: Maybe try a different name object was just a placeholder i used... Also need to mark it public probably

Comment: I have set public void load() and changed the object name from _dict to dict nothing help ... I notice that there is two object and Object keywords the last one with capital letter is it Object you are using ? also the inaccessible  errors are still exist

Comment: Change class Object to public class MyObject and try that

Comment: there is missing `)` at the end of that line after adding it ii got below errors `dict.Add(dr["PRODUCT_ID"], new Object() { ProductDesc = dr["DESCRIPTION"], UnitPrice = dr["UNIT_PRICE"] });` Errors The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,object>.Add(string, object)' has some invalid arguments
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string' 
'object' does not contain a definition for 'ProductDesc'
'object' does not contain a definition for 'UnitPrice'

Comment: I had solve error i have I still need your help at TextChanged event the dot text 'System.EventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' 
accepting a first argument of type 'System.EventArgs' could be found 
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: // See whether Dictionary contains this string.
 if (dictionary.ContainsKey("apple"))
 {
     int value = dictionary["apple"];
     Console.WriteLine(value);
 }

Comment: You can use `TB_PRODUCT_ID.Text` i was just typing e.text as an example (my comment said i guessed).

Comment: @ Dom CottonI tried that before but nothing happen no suggestion and nothing happen I tried to remove (4 sure that is wrong ) the if part but its trow exception that  says `The given key was not present in the dictionary.` ... i have update my original post with all change.. i am working on that form two says it new way I want know it